# Declaring children type in base class; Is it bad or not?

Tags: c#, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Recently I came across some code that has declared the children types as an enumeration in the base class. Here's a simple example:

```
public enum EmployeeType
{
    Manager,
    Secretary
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public EmployeeType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
    public void Manage()
    {
        // Managing
    }
}

public class Secretary : Employee
{
    public void SetMeeting()
    {
        // Setting meeting
    }
}
```

Based on my development experience, I wrote [an article](http://nefcanto.com/inheritance-and-children-types-in-base-class) about it, declaring that it's a bad practice/design. I think it's bad because the base class should be agnostic about its children classes. It should have no information about its children classes, and here are at least two reasons:

1. Extensibility: This design won't be extensible, because if you want to define another derived class, say `Developer` for example, you should also update the `EmployeeType` enumeration, to which you might not have access.
2. Paradoxical definition: Now you can write this code:

   ```
   Secretary secretary = new Secretary();
   secretary.EmployeeType = EmployeeType.Manager;
   /*
   This is absurd semantically. But syntactically, it's possible.
   */
   ```

However, as I read [Wikipedia's article about inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29), I couldn't find any answer to my question.

While it might sound arguable at first glance, I believe that inheritance should be mature enough to have a solid answer for this dilemma. Is this code bad, [smelly code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)? Or is it acceptable and justified? Why?

Comment: I think the key question is what is it used for here? If I saw the equivalent code in Java I would assume the programmer did not understand OOP...

Comment: Usually it is bad design. But in some cases (typically if the set of subtypes is limited) it can be a useful pattern, similar to the discriminating unions offered by F#.

Comment: The public setter on `Type` is pretty much always a bad idea. My above comment assumes a virtual getter with no setter, or at least a protected setter.

Comment: I made an update may worth to take a look.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem can be solved when we return to the **philosophy of when to use Inheritance**.
It is said that "*Think of inheritance as an **is a** relationship*"

When you establish an inheritance relationship between two classes, you get to take advantage of dynamic binding and polymorphism.
 **Dynamic binding** means the at runtime which method implementation to invoke, based on the class of the object.
 **Polymorphism** means you can use a variable of a superclass type to hold a reference to an object whose class is the superclass or any of its subclasses.

One of the prime benefits of dynamic binding and polymorphism is that they can help make code easier to change. If you have a fragment of code that uses a variable of a superclass type, such as Employee, you could later create a brand new subclass, such as Manager, and the old code fragment will work without change with instances of the new subclass. If Manager overrides any of Employee's methods that are invoked by the code fragment, dynamic binding will ensure that Managers's implementation of those methods gets executed. This will be true even though class Manager didn't exist when the code fragment was written and compiled.
Now back to the question, why we need a EmployeeType in Employee?
There may be functions that we would like to implement in Employee, AKA CalculateSalary()

```
CalculateSalary(){
if (EmployeeType == EmployeeType.Manager) // Add management percent }
```

Tempting reason but  what if the Employee is both a Manager and a Supervisor?
Its going to be complicated! Simply we can implement CalculateSalary() as an abstract method but we will lose the target!
Here comes the Coad's Rule:
A subclass expresses **is a special kind of** and **not is a role played by a**.
[Liskov Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) Principle is a test for 'Should I be inheriting from this type?'
Role of the thumb for the above is:

- Does TypeB want to expose the complete interface (all public methods
  no less) of TypeA such that TypeB can be used where TypeA is
  expected? Indicates Inheritance.
   e.g. A Cessna biplane will expose
  the complete interface of an airplane, if not more. So that makes it
  fit to derive from Airplane.
- Does TypeB only want only some/part of the behavior exposed by TypeA?
  Indicates need for Composition.
   e.g. A Bird may need only the fly
  behavior of an Airplane. In this case, it makes sense to extract it
  out as an interface / class / both and make it a member of both
  classes.

**As a foot note from [javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html?page=3)**:
Make sure inheritance models the is-a relationship. 
Don't use inheritance just to get code reuse.
Don't use inheritance just to get at polymorphism.
Favor composition Over Inheritance.

I think in scenarios like this, being a manager is a role played by the employee, that role may be changed over time, the role would be implemented as a composition.
As an another aspect of view in domain model, and mapping it to a relational database. It's really hard to map inheritance to the SQL model (you end up with creating columns that aren't always used, using views, etc). Some ORMs try to deal with this, but it always gets complicated quickly.
 For example Hibernate's *[One Table Per Class Hierarchy](http://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance)* approach, that violates [2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) and could cause inconsistency very likely to your sample of

```
Secretary secretary = new Secretary();
secretary.EmployeeType = EmployeeType.Manager;
```

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely bad practice. Leaving aside the dubious use of inheritance (which is in itself widely viewed as bad practice, compared with using composition), it breaks the [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) by introducing a nasty circular dependency between parent and child classes.

In redesigning the code, I'd expect to address three issues:

1. I'd remove the circular dependency, by removing the enum from the base class.
2. I'd make Employee an interface.
3. I'd look at removing the public setters, which allow any aspect of the application to modify core aspects of the employee's record, making testing and tracking down bugs far more difficult than they need be.

Comment: That does not really answer the question in my opinion, just the question "Is it bad practice in situations where dependency inversion is desirable?"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dependency inversion is desirable *always* as it reduces coupling. The question was, is breaking the dependency inversion principle an example of bad code design. The correct answer is "yes".

Comment: @DavidArno, I disagree. Based on [Project Management Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management_triangle), sometimes in **real, practical world** you don't have enough resources to use it. I agree that it's always good in theory. But in practice, sometimes you should overlook it for the sake of agility and lower costs.

Comment: @DavidArno: So, as you say, dependency inversion is only desirable in situations where a low degree of coupling is required, hence not in all situations. The question was actually more specific than whether "breaking the dependency inversion principle [is] an example of bad code design", but even as it is, it is probably too broad to answer with a clear "yes" or "no".

Comment: @SaeedNeamati As a professional developer, you have an obligation to deliver quality software; always, not just when it fits some fancy management poor-quality excuse generator. If you aren't being given the resources to do that, then you have an obligation to shout, very loudly, and to refuse to deliver. Anything else and you aren't acting professionally.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper There is *no* situation when tightly coupled software is acceptable. That is entry level, "101" software engineering knowledge. There is no excuse not to know this. Hence, dependency inversion is desirable in *ever* situation where inheritance is used.

Comment: @DavidArno: Certainly, there are various approaches at dealing with tasks. In general, I prefer carefully choosing appropriate techniques, and knowing *why* I choose them rather than following them blindly. That prevents both unfortunate design decisions in the product as well as having to resort to general accusations when I have no concrete arguments to support my point.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds bad "Code smell", I'd say poor design. but I usually do something like this and which I feel is acceptable though.

```
public enum EmployeeType
{
    UnKnown,//this can be used for extensiblity
    Manager,
    Secretary,    
}

public abstract class Employee//<--1
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public abstract EmployeeType Type { get; } //<--2
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
    public override EmployeeType Type { get { EmployeeType.Manager; } }//<--3
    public void Manage()
    {
        // Managing
    }
}

public class Secretary : Employee
{
    public override EmployeeType Type { get { EmployeeType.Secretary; } }//<--4
    public void SetMeeting()
    {
        // Setting meeting
    }
}
```

Then a factory of it..

```
EmployeeFactory.Create(employeeType);
```

I've made "4" changes in your original code and now it looks kinda "Factory pattern". May be author of the code understand the "Factory pattern" wrong. but Who knows.?

Comment: @Downvoter pls care to comment, so that I'll learn where am wrong.

Comment: Your addition of "Unknown" does not fix the fact that the pattern you create here is breaking a core aspect of good OO design: the dependency inversion principle.

Comment: I think to secure this against undesired effects, you should still make either the `Type` property of the subclasses, or the subclasses themselves, `sealed`. As a remark, I usually feel `Type` can too easily be mixed up with the (programming-).NET type of the object rather than the (business logic) type, so I usually call this kind of a property `*Kind`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper While I agree with you I plan to keep this answer as it is just to see whether any more critic comments. Coz I used it in some places. To make sure am not that worng :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Nice solution, thanks. Now imagine Microsoft would create a `AuthenticationProviderType` for some of the providers like `FrenchAuthenticationProvider` and `ChineeseAuthenticationProvider` and then have a value of `Unknown` besides it. How do you feel seeing this code in Microsoft's assembly?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: It would be clean as long as there is an additional (abstract) subclass that enforces `Type` to return `EmployeeType.Unknown`. `Unknown` in this case expresses that the type is unknown to the base class, and thus may not get any specific support that would be needed for some operations (e.g. in a serialization scenario). On the other hand, `Unknown` can also be a value used whenever referring to `Employee` subclass instances without having an actual object yet, to express that whatever was decoded or requested does not map to any of the known/available types.

Comment: Why do you need this enum `EmployeeType` if the classes themselves are already a type? I don't know C# very well, but in other languages, such as Java, you can use reflection to return a class type.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos With reflection it is possible in c# also reflection is a pain which is very poor performing thing. even you could find `employee is Manager` to see whether he is `Manager`. `EmployeeType` can help you to create an appropriate employee with factory and check which kind of employee he is *efficiently*.

Comment: I can't see this you're doing any different from a set of `is` (instanceof in other languages) verifications. Again, I'm saying I'm not used to C#, but this `System.Type type = employee.GetType();` doen't seem a lot of overhead to me, but I could be wrong...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos You're right there, on the other hand we can't rely on `CLRType` for all things. Consider `EmployeeFactory.Create(employeeType);` here `employeeType` is an enum which tells `Create` method to create which type of Employee to create "Manager" or "Labour" etc. This could be easily acheived through string `EmployeeFactory.Create("Manager");` but it looks ugly and not typesafe.. got my point?

Comment: Yes, I got it... I'm more used to Java and PHP, so normally I'd stick to the string version and throw an `Exception` if anything goes wrong...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos and string comparison also a pain. You need to aware of culture, a space char at end can screw you, unicode characters etc. So I stick with enum approach.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: It is not possible to `switch` over types, while it is possible to `switch` over `enum` values. Also, if something goes wrong (e.g. passing an invalid type identifier) with the string, you will learn as late as at runtime, whereas if something goes wrong with the `enum` value, the `enum` constant will simply not be recognized by the compiler and you'll know at compile-time. Moreover, while the `enum` type can be exposed to the outside, it is well possible that sometimes, the actual object type is unknown and hidden behind an interface, so checking for a type is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is bad practice, but in certain scenarios this might be needed or useful and if so, you can at least prevent something bad happening by making the property of the base class read only and set it via ctor of the sub classes.

```
public enum EmployeeType
{
    Manager,
    Secretary
}

public class Employee
{
    public Employee(EmployeeType type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public EmployeeType Type { get; private set; }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
    public Manager()
        : base(EmployeeType.Manager)
    {
    }

    public void Manage()
    {
        // Managing
    }
}

public class Secretary : Employee
{
    public Secretary()
        : base(EmployeeType.Secretary)
    {
    }

    public void SetMeeting()
    {
        // Setting meeting
    }
}
```

To prevent Employee be instantiated with a wrong type, you can make it protected.

In general this question is pretty broad, meaning it really depends on the overall design and I would try to prevent this from happening by refactoring/redesigning the class structures and/or logic which expects that Type property.

Comment: "but in certain scenarios..." No. If it is bad practice, rewrite it. Do not start hacking it with protected methods and the like.

Comment: @DavidArno I disagree, the question is too broad to answer this correctly. You comment is just an opinion. For example it could be you have to use another component/lib which requires something like this and you cannot prevent that from happening? So what... In general, if it is all your code, you shouldn't do something like this at all and refactor/redesign your code (as I wrote)...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good design for certain scenarios, and it certainly is a recurring pattern seen in various parts of the .NET base class library.

I think the misconception that implies it could be bad design is that class hierarchies must be extensible. However, first and foremost, an inheritance relationship just expresses that some subtype is a specialization of a supertype, and that the subtype is not the same as the supertype, but compatible with the (interface of the) supertype.

A family of types related by inheritance does *not* necessarily offer any possibilities for third parties to add any additional types. This is often, but not exclusively, the case when such a type family represents the data structures defined in a standard.

As for expressing the type of the current class with an `enum` value, nothing speaks against that if the inheritance hierarchy is limited to extension for third parties. Strictly speaking, such a property *should not* be necessary, but as languages such as C# do not offer any possibility of switching over types, offering an `enum` value improves readability of code that has to handle the different types of the type family and thus constitutes good API design. In this respect, it also improves maintainability, as future versions of the same type family might restructure the type hierarchy. Code that checks exclusively against the `enum` values will be agnostic to such changes (and error-prone workarounds such as checking against the (`string`) type name rather than the `Type` object itself will not be introduced in the first place).

The .NET BCL uses this pattern in various places, such as:

- [`XmlNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`XmlNodeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`XObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`XmlNodeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`ExpressionType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`MemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`MemberType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.membertype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that all of them are **readonly** properties. That is not the case here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: True, the code shown is not very clean - I personally would explicitly declare `Employee` as `abstract`, too, and give it a `protected` (or possibly `internal`, to prevent any third-party inheritance) constructor, as well as possibly make `Manager` and `Secretary` `sealed`. However, I understood the OP as being mainly concerned about the practice of reflecting the child classes in an `enum` type, which is IMO a more significant design decision here than the API cleanliness issues correctly pointed out by you.

Comment: Keeping these in mind and with my experience I shown how to make it acceptable approach in my answer, Have a look at it. I should have thought of these BCL classes, I missed that:)

Comment: The BCL is full of bad design, such as in this case and such as the breaking of the Liskov Substitution principle in many of the collection classes. Just because the BCL is badly designed is no excuse to design your own code badly.

Comment: @DavidArno: Do you have a concrete reason to cling to this principle in the specific situations pointed out?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The core principle behind every piece of well-designed software is loose coupling. By making a base class dependent upon its child classes, you couple those classes together. Good software design isn't something one should turn on only when convenient; it should be central to every line of code you produce.

Comment: @DavidArno: In my opinion, a core principle of software development is choosing the right tool for the task at hand. Sometimes, loose coupling is the right tool, while at other times it is not. My personal opinion is that there is no point in blindly following a principle without adapting to the actual specifics of the situation.